# Back to the view

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms, breadcrumbs

I have created a view that creates pages, each page display the terms of taxonomy of a vocabulary and their articles, how can i link the articles to those pages ?

For example :

- I have the Vocabulary Food : for which i generated a page /articles/apple
- Food has the terms of taxonomy : 'Apple'
- The article : 'Learn about appels' has the term of taxonomy 'Apple'

How do i display a link or breadcrumb for the users on the article 'Learn about appels' that redirect them to the list of 'Food' /articles/apple ?

p.s : i have many many articles, terms of taxonomy and vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default breadcrumb implementation is based on the path.

If you use Pathauto to generate aliases (with a pattern like /articles/[node:field_food_category:entity:name]/[node:title]), so that the resulting alias is /articles/apple/learn-about-apples, then the breadcrumb should just work.

The active menu trail will not, but you can use a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path for that.

A custom link will have to get the term and its URL, you can get that in preprocess_node() and then print it out in the template wherever you want.

I don't now how you handle content in different vocabularies, if it's a separate node type, or using different category fields or even a single one), based on that it will be more or less complicated to define the pathauto pattern(s), but you could always set up a custom token like [node:my_custom_category_path] to deal with that.

I'd suggest you ask more specific questions if some things are not clear yet as this gets too longer otherwise

Comment: I've used pathauto like you suggested and it works fine, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using views...

- Make a view block
- Add a field of your terms
- Edit that field's multiple display settings and uncheck "display multiple values in the same row"
- Rewrite that field with `Learn more about <a href="articles/{{Your replacement pattern}}">{{Your replacement pattern}}</a>`
- Include your view block on all content types of article.